# Setting / saving data on web server

Tags: jquery, client-server

I have a database app that I want to use a `$(window).unload` to pass the state of a set of checkboxes representing the fields to be returned.  The index file has a form containing the checkboxes.  And a set of links to call various database requests.
When a link is clicked the unload action first sets the data into localStorage then triggers a `$.getJSON()` that passes the data to the server.  However it seems the link behavior is performed prior to the `$.getJSON` and the data is not available nor do they seem to share the same scope.
I searching for any method to allow me to pass the data and have it available on all pages that perform querys.  Any thought would be appreciated.

Comment: hi.  What I'm looking for is a overarching method.  Is there a way to make data globaly vailable at the server?

Comment: I think I've settled on using $_SESSION to stor the data but I'm open to any better mechanism.